# Bash IF statement is not behaving as expected

Tags: bash, macos, exit-status

I cannot understand the logic of what's going on with this simple Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if file is present
which ./vendor/bin/non_existent_file &> /dev/null

printf "Exited with $?\n\n"

if [[ "$?" -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "Number is One"
else
  echo "Number is not one"
fi
```

When the file is missing (non existent), the output is this:

```
Exited with 1

Number is not one
```

When the file is present, the output is this:

```
Exited with 0

Number is not one
```

???

Things I've tried:

```
if [ $? == 1 ]
if [ "$?" == 1 ]
if [[ "$?" == 1 ]]
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
if [[ "$?" = "1" ]]
if [[ "$?" == "1" ]]
```

Why is the IF statement always failing?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to keep last exit status after test](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209419/how-to-keep-last-exit-status-after-test)

Comment: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
which ./vendor/bin/non_existent_file &> /dev/null
```

This will run `which` and set `$?` to its exit status. (I'll assume for now that `which` works for you.)

```
printf "Exited with $?\n\n"
```

This will run `printf`, and set `$?` to its exit status.

```
if [[ "$?" -eq 1 ]]; then
```

So what gets tested is the exit status of `printf`.

You need to save the exit status to a temporary variable to avoid that, e.g.

```
which ./vendor/bin/non_existent_file &> /dev/null
ret=$?
printf 'which exited with status %d\n' "$ret"
if [[ $ret -ne 0 ]]; then
    printf "that was a falsy exit status"
fi
```

Though `which` as I know would search `PATH` for the named executable, but if you have a fixed path you're looking at, you could probably use `[[ -x ./path ]]` directly to see if the file there is executable. If you're looking for a program in `PATH`, you may want to see [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) for caveats and corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments by @Kusalananda and @SottoVoce it becomes clear:

`$?` stores the result of the previous command, which includes `printf`.

So running `printf "Exited with $?\n\n"` changes `$?` to `0` by virtue of it having executed successfully.

It would be better to store the result of the execution in another variable to prevent this sort of confusion from happening.